# Web interactive server side 3D rendering

Tags: 3d, rendering

I need to submit 3d rendering job on an web site and receive the result, just a still image, back via URL or HTTP.

I have 3D scene and texture map ready.  Job will be sent in JavaScript.  Then 3D scene and texture in a server will be sent to renderer.  Result (still cut image) should be sent back to the website so that it can be displayed.

You can assume that I have a HTML.

What 3D rendering tools in cloud or commercial 3D renderfarm would make this available?
Otherwise, what would it takes to develop the system?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out [Render Rocket](http://www.renderrocket.com). A 3D cloud rendering service that provides support to many of the top 3D applications (Maya, 3ds Max, C4D, etc.). The process is exactly how you described. Submit the scene, render the frames, then download. You mentioned JavaScript. I am not sure about your workflow with JS, but if you have the scene in a native 3D format the JS portion might not be needed. If it is RR's pipeline is configured to accommodate many different custom workflows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I talked about it with Renderrocket.  They don't have a system that immediately fit my special need now.  But they are willing to help if something can be done.  Because i am building small prototype flow, i won't ask commercial render farm to customize their system yet.

Answer (score 1):

HDVR(R) does exactly what you are looking for, it is CPU based so it's cloud friendly. Besides its interactive quality is way above any other VR solution...

Answer (score 0):

> [IMPFarm](http://sourceforge.net/projects/impfarm/) is a renderfarm for the [POV-Ray](http://www.povray.org) raytracer. All communication is via http with XML documents. Servers and clients are cross platform. Management and reporting is done using web pages.